# How to change java for ant in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I hava an ant project with netbeans 12. There is a section

```
<action name="test.single">
    <target>test-selected-file</target>
    <context>
        <property>classname</property>
        <folder>src</folder>
        <pattern>\.java$</pattern>
        <format>java-name</format>
        <arity>
            <one-file-only/>
        </arity>
    </context>
</action>
```

in the .nbproject/project.xml file. This instructs the netbeans to run ant task "test-selected-file" in my build.xml file when run -> test file is selected from netbeans' menu.

In addition of the test the target prints the java version that ant is using:

```
Java/JVM version: 1.9
Java/JVM detail version: 11.0.12
```

This is a wrong version and it should be java 1.8. How to change this?

More information:
projects -> project name -> properties -> java sources page defines "source level JDK 1.8"

projects -> project name -> properties -> Java sources classpath defines "java platform: 1.8" (there is also java 11 available).

tools -> options -> java -> Java Shell has a Java platform with value "JDK 1.8"

Netbeans itself runs on Java 11 but ant should run on java 1.8. I have tried the following:

- Set JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD for files in /usr/share/ant which is the ANT_HOME set in netbeans.
- Set JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD in ~/.antrc
- Set ant variables JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD from netbeans menu tools -> Ant variables
- Right click build.xml -> run target -> advanced -> Special Ant properties and set JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD

If I run Ant from command line everything works:

```
 [echo] Java/JVM version: 1.8
 [echo] Java/JVM detail version: 1.8.0_202
```

How can netbeans be configured to invoke ant with Java 1.8? Is there any configuration file (e.g. project.xml) that could have this configuration? Is there even a documentation for netbeans configuration files somewhere? I could not find anything.

Comment: You need to change the JDK for the _project_. Right click on the project and select the JDK in the "Compile" section. (Project -> Build -> Compile)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no (Project -> Build -> Compile) section in my NetBeans. There is only a Compile entry which runs the ant target "compile". There is also Build enty which runs "all" ant task.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/FqImWRv.png